# Can I pass UTM parameters to Firebase Analytics user dimension?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an Android and iOS apps with Firebase Analytics that streams data into BigQuery project. I want to pass `utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign` parameters to fields `user_dim.traffic_source.user_acquired_campaign`, `user_dim.traffic_source.user_acquired_medium`, `user_dim.traffic_source.user_acquired_campaign` in BigQuery Firebase schema. Is this possible, and if yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

In order to pass utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign parameters to fields to BigQuery you must link your Google Analytics data to BigQuery as those parameters are passed to Google Analytics as shown here [1] (check the table within the document for details). Moreover, at the end of the same document you can find the relative explanation to that.

That said, and in order to export these events from Analytics for Firebase into BigQuery you may follow the documentation here [2]

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics

[2] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery